# Access runner container from compose container in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, continuous-integration

I'm using gitlab-ci runners with `docker` executor.
In my test job, I spin up a test environment using `docker compose` and then run my tests.
My tests spin up an HTTP server and execute tests against it.

Some container in the `compose` network need access to the HTTP server running in the CI runner, but I couldn't figure out how.

```
setup_test_services:
  image: docker:git
  stage: setup
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    ...
    - docker compose --env-file .env up --wait
    - yarn install
    - yarn test
  variables:
    ...
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"
    SERVICE_URL: http://build:9999
```

The `compose` services are running in the default network and I'm using `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` to connect the runner network to the docker compose network.
The container can't access my tests HTTP server though.
Please note that I'm using `docker:dind` service.
What am I doing wrong?

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job